# Wercker: How to build constantly few times a day?

Tags: continuous-integration, wercker

Right now wercker builds a build when changes were made to git repo. How do I set up wercker so it builds for example every 12 or 8 hours every day ?

Comment: I have added an issue to our backlog to add this capability.

Comment: @MarkNelson great to hear it, via CRON would be superb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible yet, although it has been suggested [here](https://wercker.uservoice.com/forums/181077-general/suggestions/6430166-build-periodically). But you could create a small program the calls the api to trigger builds periodically.